# Bing Map Aerial Question

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, bing-maps

I am aware of [Microsoft Bing Maps Aerial licensing changes with ArcGIS for Desktop](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/04/12/bing-maps-use-in-arcmap-has-changed/) at the end of this year.

My question here is why I have two different ArcMap I saved had them in it.

One was able to show it and the other would not allowed me to show me?

What is the reason for that?

ArcGIS 10.1 SP 1

Here is screenshot:

[image: Here is the Sample of the screenshot]

Comment: I would guess that the one that works is an older Map Document. Maybe you removed and added the basemap and/or recently saved the one that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Paul is on the right track regarding the differences between your two Map Documents.

Since you have Service Pack 1 installed, you can download the newly available [Set Bing Key Patch](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/67/metaid/2003) so that you can have access to Bing basemaps in all your Map Documents (10.1).  You will need to get a temporary key from ESRI which expires Dec 31st, 2013.